# Removing xterm installs gnome-terminal even if mate-terminal is installed

Tags: package-management, gnome-terminal

When I try to remove the `xterm` package then the `gnome-terminal` package is installed. The `mate-terminal` is already installed (I'm using Ubuntu-MATE) and it is an accepted alternative for x-terminal-emulator as shown here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/x-terminal-emulator.

Output of `apt-cache policy mate-terminal`:

```
thanos@thanos-GA-970A-DS3:~$ apt-cache policy mate-terminal
mate-terminal:
  Installed: 1.14.1-1~xenial1.1
  Candidate: 1.14.1-1~xenial1.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.14.1-1~xenial1.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/xenial-mate/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.12.1-1 500
        500 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Output of `apt-cache show mate-terminal | grep ^Provides`:

```
thanos@thanos-GA-970A-DS3:~$ apt-cache show mate-terminal | grep ^Provides
Provides: x-terminal-emulator
Provides: x-terminal-emulator
```

**EDIT: Even if I install `lxterminal` the proglem is the same and `gnome-terminal` is installed. So what package could possibly need only `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` and rejects any other option? (I don't think that the problem is the `x-terminal-emulator` virtualpackage)**

Comment: @Zanna lol you are right, I must be blind. I ll delete my question in a few minutes. But still why removing `xterm` installs `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: @Zanna haha didn't think of that :P

Comment: @ThanosApostolou: What's the output of `apt-cache policy mate-terminal` and `apt-cache show mate-terminal | grep ^Provides`?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch I edited the question. I'm using the mate xenial ppa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not because of `x-terminal-emulator` as your `mate-terminal` package provides that. Some packages don't depend on `x-terminal-emulator` but on some specific terminals.

If you have `aptitude` installed

```
aptitude why gnome-terminal
```

should tell you why `gnome-terminal` is needed.

Comment: Thx I learned something new. It was the `steam-launcher` package that wants only `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` or `konsole`.